# Joining two dataframes to remove NaN values in the first dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I would like to merge two dataframe columns.

I have df1 and that has a specific column (df$col1). This column has rows 1-100, certain rows have NA values (lets say rows 10,15,20,50,69).

Dataframe 2 has rows 10,15,20,50,69.

Is it possible to merge DF2 to df$col such that only the NA values in df$col are filled by DF2..depending on the index number for each dataset

I tried this but instead got a dataframe that did not look anything like what I want

```
merge(brfss2$pa1min_,df,by.x=1,by.y=1,all.x=TRUE,all.y=TRUE)
```

Here are the two dataframes

Dataframe1:

```
1 NA
2 110
3 NA
4 35
5 NA
6 120
7 280
8 30
9 240
10 260
11 322
12 NA
```

Dataframe 2:

```
1 2127.6
3 1403.0
5 198.0
12 112.8
```

Comment: Try join `library(data.table);setDT(df1)[df2, v2 := i.v2, on = .(v1)]` assuming 'v1', 'v2' as columns in both datasets.  Do you have cases where some duplicate elements for first column have values and not want to replace it?

Comment: Maybe I should add this to the question df1 is actually a column from an existing dataframe...no duplicates

Comment: also suppose you have `12 24` in first dataset and there is a value in dataset2, then it shouldn't get replaced?

Comment: @akrun that won't happen dataset2 only has values for rows that correspond with NA values in the first dataset

Comment: ok, then my solution should work

Comment: getting this error message -> Argument 'x' to 'setDT' should be a 'list', 'data.frame' or 'data.table'

Comment: Do you have a `matrix` or data.frame 'DF1'

Comment: Its a dataframe but I am selecting one column from the dataframe e.g setDT(brfss2$pa1min_)[df,v2:=iv2, on= .(v1)]

Comment: That converts it to a `vector`.  Assuming that the first dataset is 'brfss2', `setDT(brfss2)[df, v2 := i.v2, on = .(v1)]`. Here, I assume the column names as 'v1', 'v2'.  If it is different, make changes accordingly.  i.e. `pa1min_`

Comment: @akrun makes sense...but df literally only has one column...the numbers are the index

Comment: In that case, create a column from the row number and then do the join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a different method - I imported your data and gave column names:

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12
), col2 = c(NA, 110, NA, 35, NA, 120, 280, 30, 240, 260, 322, 
NA)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(col1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), col2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 2), class = "col_spec"))

df2 <- structure(list(col1 = c(1, 3, 5, 12), col2 = c(2127.6, 1403, 
198, 112.8)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -4L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
col1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector"
)), col2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 2), class = "col_spec"))
```

Using `tidyverse` you can merge and then add a new column conditionally based on the value without `NA`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  merge(df2, by = "col1", all.x = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(new_col = if_else(is.na(col2.x), col2.y, col2.x)) %>% 
  select(new_col)

   new_col
1     2127.6
2     110.0
3     1403.0
4     35.0
5     198.0
6     120.0
7     280.0
8     30.0
9     240.0
10    260.0
11    322.0
12    112.8
```

Comment: Thanks. But in this case the numbers appearing in col1 are the index

Comment: then using `dplyr::rowid_to_column()` for both your dfs will provide the column to merge.

Comment: @Emm there seems to be some confusion over index numbers versus columns - you may wish to edit your question to reflect this or `dput` both dfs.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the package [*safejoin*](https://github.com/moodymudskipper/safejoin) which solves this very succinctly

```
# devtools::install_github("moodymudskipper/safejoin")
safe_left_join(df1,df2, by = "col1", conflict = dplyr::coalesce)
# # A tibble: 12 x 2
#     col1  col2
#    <dbl> <dbl>
#  1     1 2128.
#  2     2  110 
#  3     3 1403 
#  4     4   35 
#  5     5  198 
#  6     6  120 
#  7     7  280 
#  8     8   30 
#  9     9  240 
# 10    10  260 
# 11    11  322 
# 12    12  113.
```